# How to select MIN and MAX from a table and select their related name from another table?

Tags: sql, oracle

Table `A`  has `product_id` and `product_name`.

Table `B` has `product_id` and its related `values`.

How can I select the `product_name` (from table `A`) with `min` and `max` of the values (from table `B`)?

The expected results:

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. 
my expected results:
NAME MAXIMAL MINIMAL
Name_1 11 5
Name_2 15 8
Name_3 8 4
Name_4 3 2
Name_5 12 9

Comment: your answer gives me two errors:
SQL Error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
result SQL Statement is wrong

Comment: Please tag your post correctly. You have tagged it with sql-server and trying to run it in Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select product_name, MAX(value) as Maximal, MIN(value) as Minimal from a, b
where a.product_id = b.product_id 
group by product_name
```

Comment: Please, add a description to your answer. Code-only answers are useless for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want `join` and `group by`?

```
select a.product_id, a.product_name, min(b.value), max(b.value)
from a join
     b
     on a.product_id = b.product_id
group by a.product_id, a.product_name;
```